# Convert text to certain numbers in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How do I convert String to elements in an array  In the language kotlin ?
 example  (" Hello ")
[h] [e] [l]  [l]  [o]

thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-char-array.html)?

Comment: Use the to String.toCharArray(); function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s as simple as this:

```
"Hello World".toCharArray()
```